# String Compare Failure in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string

```
 <div id="error" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_head">Activation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">


                    **<p id="error_record"> <?php echo $msg; ?> </p>**           \\line 1


                    <p class="text-warning"><small id="direction"></small></p>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" align="center">
                    <button onclick="redirect()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Okay</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to compare the string in the div with id "error_record" as follows :

```
<script>
        window.onload=function()
        {
            $("#error").modal('show');
        }
        function redirect(){
            var val=document.getElementById("error_record").innerHTML;      \\line2
            alert(val);                                                      \\line 3
            if(val=="Invalid Link"||val=="Invalid Link."||val=="Empty Link")
            {
                window.location="index.php";
            }
            if(val=="Activation Successful"||val=="Your Account is already activated.")
            {
                window.location="dashboard.php";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But it always returns false in the comparison, in comment line 2.

The alert in comment line 3 gives the same string, But the comparison returns false.

Does it have something to do with the echo in line 1?

i have
    $msg="Empty Link";

Comment: what do you mean by "But it always returns false in the comparison, in comment line 1."

Comment: please read $msg="Empty Link";

The string ought to be same but the comparison doesnt work.

Comment: try to add this add this => val = val.trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have whitespaces where i have written underscores `<p id="error_record">_<?php echo $msg; ?>_</p>`,
that is why your strings are not equat.
Either remove the whitespaces, or use `.trim()` fuction on your innerHTML to remove the whitespace.

Comment: You mean all the white spaces??

Comment: no, only inside `<p>` tag ( the ones that i replaced with the underscores ) the whitespaces inside $msg are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using (double equals) `==`

use `indexOf() != -1` as shown  below code and let me know whether it works or not:

```
if(val.indexOf("Activation Successful")!=-1||val.indexOf("Your Account is already activated.")!=-1) {
    window.location="dashboard.php";
}
```